# Does it make sense to store a git repo on Ubuntu One?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, git

I'm working on a small project, mostly at home, but I'd like to be able to access my git repo from multiple machines, all of which are connected to Ubuntu One.

Do you think I can safely store my repo in U1 and work from there, or will that get me into trouble?

Comment: Thought anything about using a more git dedicated service, such as github or similar?

Comment: I don't want to pay anything -- $7/mo is cheap, but I've been trying to belt-tighten.

Comment: use dropbox (With referrals to friends or your other email accounts, you can have a LARGE amount of space for $0/mo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely - there are questions and discussions on StackOverflow about doing this with DropBox (which is extremely similar to what you are asking):

[is-this-plain-stupid-git-sharing-via-dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199637/is-this-plain-stupid-git-sharing-via-dropbox)

and

[using-gitdropbox-together-effectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively)

Comment: Thanks -- from these links, it looks like this should be workable for me. But, to clarify, when you say "most likely" do you mean that this most likely makes sense, or that this is likely to get me into trouble? :)

Comment: Most likely should work - especially since you mention it's a small project.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll add an edit or comment here if things go horribly wrong.

Comment: Remember to wait until U1 has synced the changed files to the cloud before switching off the computer you last worked on though...

Comment: and please, let us know how it goes! file bugs if it fails :)